# Как определить textarea в фокусе и есть ли там текст?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста функцию проверки в фокусе ли `<textarea></textarea>`? И функцию проверки есть ли текст в `<textarea></textarea>`

Просто хочу сделать так чтобы изначально был виден один `<textarea></textarea>`, но при фокусе появляется кнопка `Отправить`, как только фокус пропадает, то убирать `Отправить`, но вот тут я хочу сделать проверку если фокуса нет, но там есть текст, то `Отправить` не убирать.

Подскажите пожалуйста как определить присутствует ли текст в `<textarea></textarea>` и в фокусе ли `<textarea></textarea>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так:

```js
var textarea = document.getElementById('Text_block');
var btn = document.getElementById('Awesome_button');
textarea.addEventListener('input', function(e){
 
 if(this.value != '') {
  btn.classList.add('active')
 } else {
  btn.classList.remove('active')
 }
})
```

```css
button {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: 300ms;
  transition: 300ms;
}
button.active {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<textarea name="" id="Text_block" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
<button id="Awesome_button">Send me</button>
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, отличный способ, только на фокус не появляется, но я уже знаю как все реализовать, спасибо

Comment: да, я просто пропустил момент с фокусом )

Comment: подскажите, как решить вариант если присутствуют таких два  и более блока `<textarea name="" id="Text_block" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
<button id="Awesome_button">Send me</button>`